# A similar lemma to a lemma due to Lagarias, for the partial sums of reciprocal of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

I was inspired in Lemma 3.1 of [1] and in the Theorem 4.12 of [2] to ask about a similar statement that shows Lagarias in his paper as Lemma 3.1.

The Lemma from Lagarias's paper is that if $H(n)=\sum_{i \leq n} \frac{1}{i}$, then for $n\geq 3$ we have $$e^{H(n)}\log H(n) \geq e^{\gamma}n \log \log n,$$ where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.

We define for integers $n\geq 1$ 
$$h_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{p_k},$$
where $p_k$ denotes the $k$-th prime number.

> **Question.** I wondered if it is possible to determine a lower bound as a function of $n$ such that 
>   $$\text{lower bound}(n)\leq \exp(h_n)\log(h_n)$$
>   holds $\forall n\geq N$ for some suitable integer $N\geq 1$.

I am asking about a statement similar to the lemma due to Lagarias, including a reference to the literature if available.

### References:

[1] Jeffrey C. Lagarias, [*An Elementary Problem Equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2695443), The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 109, No. 6 (Jun. - Jul., 2002), pp. 534–543.  ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1908008))

[2] Tom M. Apostol, [*Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-28579-4), Undergraduate Text in Mathematics Springer (1976).  ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=434929))

Comment: Note that what you denote by $h_{n}$ is known to be asymptotic to $\log\log n+M$ where $M$ is the so-called Meissel-Mertens constant.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks @SylvainJULIEN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments $h_n\sim \log\log n +M,$ so for $n$ large enough we can write 
$$e^{h_n}\log h_n \sim e^M \log n \log(\log \log n+M)\quad(1).$$ 
For $n$ large the right hand side can be approximated by
$$
e^M \log n \left(\log \log\log n+\frac{M}{\log \log n}\right)
$$

where $M$ is the Mertens-Meissel constant. Whether the difference between any of these two RHS's and $\exp\{h_n\} \log h_n$ has a definite sign after some large $n$ is probably hard to prove. In fact in the taylor expansion I used in the approximation above there should probably be a $$-\frac{M^2}{(\log\log n)^2}$$
to ensure a lower bound.

But the question is, what is your goal?

**Edit:** Computations with Magma online calculator give the following for the left hand side (actual) and the right hand side (approx.) of (1)

```
n= 2^ 10: actual 7.1385169507832789173 approx 7.0886111103586373676 
diff 0.049905840424641549657

n= 2^ 15: actual 12.926526293730941052 approx 12.919605358113649214
diff 0.0069209356172918385427

n= 2^ 20: actual 19.115096320844860339 approx 19.113668933136581336
diff 0.0014273877082790029525
```

At $n=2^{21},$ the largest value where the computation terminates [the online calculator has a time limit] the difference is down to $0.001249\cdots$ but still positive.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.